# How do a create a reusable simple custom list style with my own color and spacing

Tags: listview, swiftui

I want all the lists in my application to look exactly the same and don't want to respecify all these settings over and over.  I get the following error: Cannot find type 'Configuration' in scope. I currently have something like this:

```
struct CustomListStyle: ListStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(configuration.data, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item as? String ?? "")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .padding(10) 
                        .background(Color.gray) 
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
            .padding() 
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<10, id: \.self) { index in
            Text("Item \(index)")
        }
        .listStyle(CustomListStyle())
    }
}
```

Edit - 1 - Here is one for reference

```
List( selection: $dm.someVar ) {
    Section( ) {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [
            GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 120)),
        ], alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            ForEach(0..<20, id: \.self) { index in
                Text("Column1 abcdef: \(index)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to write your own `ListStyle`s. You should use a combination of the list modifiers, like `listRowInsets`, `listRowBackground`, `listRowSeparatorTint` etc. You can extract that into a view modifier.

Comment: Sorry, very new to Swift (3ish weeks so far) so I'm not sure.  I got this idea from Chat GPT.  Of course, I want to define a single list control that is re-usable.  I'm randomly getting row dividers on some of my lists.  Not sure where they are coming from.  Making a single list control would solve that issue.

Comment: Forget about reusable for a minute here. Do you know how to make your list in a non-reusable way? If you don’t even know that, perhaps it’s better to start from there.

Comment: Huh... I have 3 lists in my application so far.  They all work but I have to add the same modifiers to them and it would be easy to make a mistake and forget a modifier for future lists.  I just created a re-usable CFFloat TextField() and want to do the same thing for lists.

Comment: Edit your question and show some code of those lists then, especially the parts that you want to make resusable.

Comment: Huh, I'm not asking about those lists.  I want to create a totally new thing.  A re-usable list control. Not sure why your asking for a very standard list control that works.

Comment: I want to add things like .listRowSeparator(.hidden) which will remove the lines between rows and some appearance things such as row padding, the selection color to match the users selection color (system selection) etc.  I didn't include that information since I thought I could get that stuff to work once I got a Customizable list control.

Comment: Implementation for ListStyle isnt public, so you can’t implement regardless of what ChatGPT says. In general ChatGPT is not a good resource for SwiftUI, because it has changed so much over the years and the biggest changes aren’t even included.

Comment: @loremipsum Understood, how do I make this happen then?  IOW:  Is there another way?

Comment: ViewModifiers, Custom Views that use Generics, SwiftUI.Layout, there are a ton if options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to implement a `ListStyle`, you can let Xcode add stubs for protocol conformance. You will then see, that the required functions all start with `_`. This is a clue, that the protocol `ListStyle` is not intended to be used for custom implementations.

However, you might be able to achieve what you're after by creating a wrapper for a `List` that accepts a `ViewBuilder` as parameter. Something like:

```swift
struct CustomList<Content>: View where Content: View {
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    var body: some View {
        List {
            content()
                .listRowBackground(
                    Color.yellow
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                )
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .listRowSpacing(10)
        .foregroundStyle(.pink)
        .padding()
        .background(.gray)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomList {
            ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { item in
                Text("Item \(item)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Benzy, I'll try this out later today.  Need to be sure it works with LazyGrid... as most of my lists have 2 or 3 columns.  Maybe I'll pass the list and put the for each inside the custom list.  I'll play with it.  I don't mind having more code in lower level code if it means I can have simpler code at a higher level.